# Access Join Table Like

Tags: ms-access, join, sql-like

I have an access db which contains two tables.

TableEquipments , 
Table one has a coulmn named EquipmentID  containings data as below.

```
EQUIPMENTID
----------
110-TX-20
```

Second tabel is Table Manual , 
Table Manual has a column named EquipmentNO as below.

```
EQUIPMENTNO
------------------
110-TX-20 120-XX-23
```

I want to join Manual table to Eqipment table , where EQUIPMENTNO contains EQUIPMENTID.

Result I have imagined as below.

```
EQUIPMENTID    EQUIPMENTNO
-----------    ------------
110-TX-20      110-TX-20 120-XX-23
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
select . . .
from TableEquipments as te inner join
     TableManual as tm
     on instr(" " & tm.equipmentno & " ", " " & te.equipmentid & " ") > 0;
```

Note:  You appear to have a really really bad data model, storing lists of things in a column.  You should have another table with one row per "manual" (whatever that is) and equipment id.

Comment: Thank for your kind attention.It worked.You right on data modellin, but i am not creating db, i need this code to analyse already created two excel tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I couldn't figure out how to invite you to chat, but you I thought it was a fun experiment to see when the last time you took a day off from SO was. spoiler: Christmas Day 2015. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/612476/gordon-linoffs-days-off-since-2014

Comment: @SqlZim . . . It is more complicated than that.  There are 24 hours periods when I've not been on Stack Overflow, but they don't necessary correspond to days in London.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Cut me some slack for using UTC Days. The point was that your level of dedication and contribution is impressive, not just in reputation or points, but also in daily commitment. It was meant as a compliment :P